# What is the purpose of recursive page tables?

Tags: x86, operating-system, page-tables

I've read that there's a technique for page table translation that is called "recursive page tables" (https://os.phil-opp.com/advanced-paging/).

I think I understand the technique, but can't see the purpose of this. For example, we can reach "Page Directory" (I use Intel's notation) by writing address of this PD to, e.g. 1023 entry of the table (assume 32-bit paging for simplicity), that is accessing virtual address `0xfffff000` we'll reach PD page. Similar way we can reach "Page Table" and so on, right?

Using "recursive page tables" we need to write down the address of PD to PDE. Using usual mapping we also need to know address of PD to be able to access it, but know we just need to write it to PTE, so is there real benefit or what is this for?

Comment: Most processes only use a small amount of virtual address-space.  If you just had one flat array of PTEs, every process would need 4 MiB of page-table space, most of them "not present".  A tree can be sparse by having a not-present PDE.  When 386 was new, that was a huge fraction of the total system memory.  (4B per PTE x 1024^2 entries). [How does multi-level page table save memory space?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29467510) / [Why using hierarchical page tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9834542)

Comment: @PeterCordes, IIUC we can use recursive page tables to reduce number of levels, e.g. when processor sees 4-levels using recursive page tables we can reduce it to 3-level page table keeping a pointer to the top level table in that table, this way we should save 4KiB (or more if there are > 1 PTs) by not allocating the lowest level?

Comment: For systems like x86-64 (*[Why in x86-64 the virtual address are 4 bits shorter than physical (48 bits vs. 52 long)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46509152)*) I've never heard of having a PML4 entry point at its own physical page to have that page also double as a PDP (page-directory pointer) table.  That entry pointing to its own page would also apply to each level down to PTE (page table entry), so if a kernel did that for a user-space page, there'd be a virtual page address that would let the process read its own page table.  (That entry could be marked read-only, so it couldn't write.)

Comment: The normal way to use fewer levels is CPU support for largepages / hugepages, where the 2nd-lowest or 3rd-lowest level can point to a contiguous range of physical pages.  e.g. x86-64 largepages are 2MiB, the same amount normally covered by a whole table of PTEs for 4K pages.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_Size_Extension

Comment: Is there a reason for user space process to read its own page tables? This looks like an opportunity for security hole, unprivileged process could figure out the address of kernel page table part (if that is mapped, i.e. no page table isolation)?

Comment: Exactly, that's one reason OSes wouldn't want to do this, and AFAIK don't in practice.  I'm not sure it's harmful for user-space to learn physical addresses, though, and they wouldn't learn kernel virtual addresses because those are implicit by position, and any kernel mappings would have the user/supervisor bit set to supervisor only.  They could only read the 4KiB of entries in this one table that was recursively mapped that way.  PTEs have some spare bits for bookkeeping (marked AVL = available for kernel use, https://wiki.osdev.org/Paging#64-Bit_Paging) so user-space could read that.